# C# - Accessing ToolStripMenuItem Control from another .CS File

Tags: c#

I've got this line of code:

```
checkForUpdatesToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
```

However, it gives me the error:

> The name 'checkForUpdatesToolStripMenuItem' does not exist in the
>   current context

The issue is, how do I access the item (checkForUpdatesToolStripMenuItem) from the current .CS file I'm working in, where 'checkForUpdatesToolStripMenuItem' is part of a form?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value to the other class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Send_ToolStrip_Data_To_Instance_Class()
    {
        My_Other_CS_File other_File = new My_Other_CS_File();
        other_File.Act_On_ToolStrip_Item(checkForUpdatesToolStripMenuItem.Enabled);
    }
}
public class My_Other_CS_File
{
    public void Act_On_ToolStrip_Item(bool enabled)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how you use these classes. I'm an old school C programmer, so understanding this is strange. Where do I put these classes? In my Form.CS code (highest level/main), or in the CS file I'm working in where I'm trying to get "checkForUpdatesToolStripMenuItem" to work?

Comment: Classes can be in one file or in separate files. Think of instance classes like independent objects that can only communicate with their creator. If you create your instance class (cs file) from inside your form class, then you need to pass anything to it from the form class. Alternatively, you can create a static class that is visible to all instance classes (using public static class myClass{} Whether the actual code is in one file or the other is of no consequence.

Comment: The namespace contains everything whether it's in one file or many. As far as C# is concerned, the location of the code doesn't matter as long as it's all under the same namespace. Instance classes (those created with new ClassName()) are only known to their creators. Static classes are known to all classes. Basically.

Comment: Now I get: 'Form.checkForUpdatesToolStripMenuItem' is inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: Sorry I missed this before. That error is due to something being marked private when it needs to be marked public. Only things marked public can be seen from other classes. Change Form.checkForUpdatesToolStripMenuItem from private to public (and Form from private to public as well, if necessary) and you'll be good to go. If you get "inconsistentAvailability" errors, you're looking at the same public/private issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace SO_Question_win
```

{
    //EVERYTHIG under the same namespace might as well be in the sale file as far as C# is concerned. We use different files for convenience. 
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //this is the form class for the main form in the project. It is where the thread goes when the program starts. No other instance classes will exist until they are created

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void hello()
    {
        //I can only call hello from inside this class.
        My_Other_CS_File other_File = new My_Other_CS_File();
        //you created this instance class here. It will only exist until "hello" finishes running, then it will disappear.
        string hello = "hi";
        //the only way to get the string hello to the class you created is to pass it.
        other_File.SayHello(hello);
        //other_file is done. It will disappear now if you want it again you will have to create a new instance
    }
}
public class My_Other_CS_File
{
    public void SayHello(string hi)
    {
        //here, the string Hi is passed from the form class 
        Console.WriteLine(hi);
        //even though this class was created by the form class, it has access to any public static classes. 
        Console.WriteLine(Global.helloString);
    }
}
public static class Global
{
    //anything marked "public static" here will be visible to any class under the same namespace. This class is niether created nor destroyed - it always exists. hat's the difference bewtween static and instance.
    public static string helloString = "howdy";
}
```

}

Comment: In a simplistic way, classes are like old-time functions. If you have a need for repetitive code or need to organize a "function," just put it in a class, where you can call it up whenever you want. Unlike 2D "functions," however, classes can have many different variables, methods - they can be like mini programs and can inherit and do all kinds of cool things. But basically, they are like hyperfunctions.